# Running multiple models in parallel with different GPUs in Tensorflow for Prediction in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, tensorflow-slim

**Describe the problem**
I am using  2 GPUs GTX 1080 TI, 11GB, with CUDA/cuDNN version 9.1. cudnn 7.1 on OS (Debian 9).

I would like to run two models for prediction in two different GPUs to speed up the running time (by creating two instances of sessions in two GPUs).
the first model is computing to the first GPU and the second is computing in the second GPU by executing each session for a specific device, something like that in python "with tf.device('/gpu:0') "

**Source code**

```
int GPUID = std::stoi(params->getGpuDeviceStr());
setenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "", GPUID);

std::cout << "Initial  visible_device_list : "<<session_options.config.gpu_options().visible_device_list() << std::endl;
session_options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);
session_options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(
        params->getGpuMemoryRatio());
```

**output**

```
2018-04-30 10:18:56.625199: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1208] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.683
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0
totalMemory: 10,91GiB freeMemory: 10,75GiB
2018-04-30 10:18:56.750435: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1208] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.683
pciBusID: 0000:42:00.0
totalMemory: 10,91GiB freeMemory: 10,42GiB
2018-04-30 10:18:56.751296: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1223] Device peer to peer matrix
2018-04-30 10:18:56.751324: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1229] DMA: 0 1
2018-04-30 10:18:56.751332: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1239] 0: Y Y
2018-04-30 10:18:56.751337: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1239] 1: Y Y
2018-04-30 10:18:56.751345: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1308] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-04-30 10:18:57.110046: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:989] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10055 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-04-30 10:18:57.110819: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:989] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10050 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:42:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Running tensorflow in Version 1.5.0
```

**Discussion**

I cannot see any improvement in time-consuming by running two model simultaneously by creating two threads to run two models in two GPUs. the time consuming by running two model in two GPUs is approximately the same as running by using only one GPU.

Comment: more interesting is that when I increase the set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction in one session it effects to the second session and Total Dedicated Memory becomes the same for both GPUs, but only one GPU is used during prediction (GPU Utilization) according to NVIDIA X Server Settings. furthermore i did not connect GPUs via SLI.

Comment: Are you sure the GPU is the bottleneck? Maybe the limiting factor is data load from your disk, for example, and then the number of GPUs doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, Sir for your reply, I uncommented this option "set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction", and still no improvement. 

//session_options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(params->getGpuMemoryRatio());
 tensorflow::SessionOptions session_options;

setenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "",GPUID);
m_session.reset(tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
 // Load graph into session
    Status session_create_status = m_session->Create(graphDefinition);

Comment: As Peter mentioned, your bottleneck can be in some other part of the system. You can use tools like timeline (https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d) to see what runs when.